# audio.duration возвращает infinity, почему?

Tags: javascript

При этом currentTime работает корректно.
А вот duration работать не хочет, что не так? При этом если песня на сервере полностью проигралась - duration определяется правильно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<audio src="../assets/tracks/104_Skriptonit_Miyagi_-_NE_ZHAL_68476686.mp3" data-musicid="0" class="track_audio"></audio>

 $('.track_audio').trigger('load');
    var audio = document.querySelector('.track_audio');
    
    const updateProgress = function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.currentTime);
        console.log(e.target.duration);
    }
    
    
    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgress)
    
    console.log(audio.duration)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу после объявления audio (т. е., по ходу загрузки страницы) до выполнения остального кода не успевают загрузиться метаданные из аудиофайла, (audio.duration) поэтому вывод этого свойства следует обернуть функцией

```js
    audio.onloadedmetadata = function(){console.log(this.duration)};
     // или
audio.onloadeddata = function(){console.log(this.duration)};
```

другие альтернативные случаи, когда выводится duration:

1. временная задержка после объявления audio с помощью **setTimeout()**.
2. вывод duration по нажатию на кнопку или другому событию: (можно автоматическому)

**button.onclick = "console.log(audio.duration)";**

3. Когда слишком много строк кода между объявлением audio и выводом duration.

В Вашем случае выводится уже после того, как начинает играть.

Comment: А как получить duration до воспроизведения? preload в html прописан (metadata)

Comment: А и тогда такой вопрос, как вообще сейчас в js инициировать загрузку media?

Comment: **preload** - это сам факт загрузки данных, но выводить их нужно после окончания загрузки. Для этого обернуть в **onloadedmetadata** или **onloadeddata** в зависимости от того, нужно только метаданные загрузить или все данные, включая аудиоданные.